# Google Cloud GKE evictable vs non-evictable memory

Tags: logging, memory, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google

we have few pods inside Google Cloud K8S GKE and google metrics is reporting high memory usage in some of them but I cannot find why. Inside pod everything looks fine.
We are using GKE version 1.21.13-gke.900

[gcp memory reporting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS9w3.png)

Answer (score 0):

In short, Kubernetes does the orchestration, the rest are services that would run on top of Kubernetes. GKE brings you all these components out-of-the-box, and you don't have to maintain them. They're set up for you, and they're more 'integrated' with the Google portal.